# Laravel - Don't fire events when seeding database

Tags: laravel-5

I have a service provider which defines which models to observe in the boot method, e.g:

```
Task::observe(TaskObserver::class);
```

In `TaskObserver.php` I am listening for the `updated` event that fires when the model is updated.

When this happens, the Notification facade send an email to a collection of clients:

```
Notification::send($clients, new TaskUpdated($task));
```

Everything is working fine, but the problem I have is when I seed my database, I get an error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
  __clone method called on non-object`

My table seeder makes use of a factory which simply returns the values needed to create a model.

Why is the `updated` event firing when a Task is being created by the factory? And is there a way of avoiding the error when running the seeder?

**Seeder:**

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        ...
        $this->call(TasksTableSeeder::class);
        ...
    }
}

class TasksTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        factory(Task::class, 50)->create();
    }
}

$factory->define(Task::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'description' => $faker->sentence(8),
        'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),
    ];
});
```

Comment: please post your seeding file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `createQuietly` instead of `create` in your seeder.

```php
public function run()
{
     Contact::factory(50)->createQuietly();
}
```

Comment: Do you know in which version createQuietly was added?

Comment: As of v8.59 I believe, there's a whole slew of them `updateQuietly` etc. :)